# Symbolic math engines barf on this ostensibly tractable integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution, signal-processing, symbolic-computation

$$\frac14 \int_{-M\pi}^{N\pi - s} \cos(tu/M) \cos((t+s)u/M)(1-\cos(t/M))(1-\cos((t+s)/N))\space \mathrm d t$$

with integer $u$.

Alpha runs out of time.

Maxima gives a tremendous result that can definitely be simplified by applying such identities as $\sin(x+\pi) = \sin(x - \pi) = -\sin(x)$, but even the use of **scsimp** doesn't help.

I've been waiting at least 20 minutes for SymPy to give me an answer.

**Am I doomed to do this by hand?** It would be error prone.

Some might care about the following, some not:

I'm trying to convolve a cosine under a Hann function with a cosine under a wider Hann function. This definite integral is one of two cases in this problem. Stating it this way allows me to avoid piecewise-type functions that are zero outside a certain interval. If there's another approach I'd love to learn about it.

Comment: What is the variable you're integrating? (There's no $dx$ factor in the integrand)

Comment: Oops! dt. I have edited the question.

Comment: I think you also suffer from a parentheses imbalance.

Comment: Gah! But the expression I gave these engines was correct. Edited. Again.

Comment: @MackTuesday Can you tell me anything about M,N,u and s?

Comment: u is an integer, but I don't think I can constrain the other variables.

Comment: Wait, actually, you may assume the parameters are all positive. Not that that helps.

Comment: I fed the output of Maxima to SymPy's simplify() and got an even bigger result, one that was clearly factorable.

Comment: There are three $M$s in the integrand in what you've written, and one $N$. Is that what you intended? Given the other symmetries, I'd have expected two of each.

Comment: Yes. It's two cosines of the same frequency under two Hann windows of different width. One of the ... Ah! M/N is rational! Let's see if that helps...

Comment: But anyway, u/M says that there are u whole cycles under the window of width M, and both modulated cosines have the same frequency. Then M is the width of one window and N is the width of the other. So you get two cosines with M, a (1-cos) with M, and a (1-cos) with N.

Comment: The trick is to expand this out using $2\cos(x)=\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)$, consolidate the terms as $\int\exp(Ct)\,\mathrm{d}t$ then execute it.

Comment: Thanks, but that makes it worse. These tools aren't all that smart. That *was* how I ended up doing it by hand, but the solution is big no matter how you slice it. I'm going another route now.